# Slow Gradle compilation with shared read-only dependency cache

Tags: java, performance, gradle

I'm running Gradle builds in a CI environment using the [shared read-only dependency cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:shared-readonly-cache). This dependency cache definitely improves performance on my CI builds, but not as much as I was hoping.

When the $GRADLE_HOME directory is empty, my compilation time is around 2 minutes. When the $GRADLE_HOME directory is pre-populated, the compilation time is around 30 seconds. Note that for these tests, I stopped all daemon processes before running the compilation task, so any caching that the daemon performs is not relevant.

I've narrowed down the slow performance to two files: `$GRADLE_HOME/caches/7.5.1/javaCompile/classAnalysis.bin` and `$GRADLE_HOME/caches/7.5.1/javaCompile/jarAnalysis.bin`. When these files are not present, the compilation takes 2 minutes. When they are present, the compilation takes 30 seconds.

What do these files contain, and why do they affect compilation times so much?

Other potentially useful information:

- OS: Amazon Linux 2
- EC2 instance type: c5.xlarge
- Java version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8
- Gradle version: 7.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradle home folder was on an EBS volume. I found that the slow performance doesn't happen when the home folder is on local storage on the EC2 instance. I changed the instance type to `c6id.xlarge`, which has local NVMe-based SSD block-level storage.

Therefore I think my issue is related to EBS and not Gradle itself. Increasing the provisioned IOPS and throughput of the EBS volume didn't help, so running Gradle on local storage seems to be the solution.